# Set.Seed function - I don't get why we need it in training data

Tags: r

I don't understand why we use the set.seed function in testing/training data. I realize it randomly generates a memorable sequence for reproduction but we don't rely on it in the code itself after we set the function. Here is the code example:

```
data(mtcars)

## 75% of the sample size
smp_size <- floor(0.75 * nrow(mtcars))

## set the seed to make your partition reproducible
set.seed(123)
train_ind <- sample(seq_len(nrow(mtcars)), size = smp_size)

train <- mtcars[train_ind, ]
test <- mtcars[-train_ind, ]
```

Comment: The `sample()` function you're calling is dependent on the seed. Since you use that function to partition training and testing data, it matters what piece of the data are seen subsequently.

Comment: `set.seed` helps with reproducibility of same ***exact*** test/train split.

Answer (score 0):

Without set.seed it is much more difficult to understand how the changes you make affect the output. When editing and testing the effects of parameters we set.seed so it is the same set of random numbers every time. Without set.seed you'd be comparing number from a different random set with each code run, and so any edits you'd have are hard to compare the outputs between.